# Using Excel InputBox to capture a sheet name in C#

Tags: c#, excel-interop

I would like to use an Excel `InputBox()` to capture the name of a sheet by clicking on it, or it's tab. However, when I use the following code:

```
Excel.Application _excel = this.Application; // this refers to an C# excel addin.
// ...
var result = _excel.InputBox(
             "prompt",
             "Sheet Selection",
             Type.Missing,
             Type.Missing,
             Type.Missing,
             Type.Missing,
             Type.Missing,
             Type.Missing);
```

I get the result

> "='Sheet Name'!"

but instead what I would like is

> "Sheet Name"

I've tried using the `InputBox` text specifier (2) as mentioned [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.excel._application.inputbox%28v=office.11%29.aspx) but this doesn't seem to make any difference. Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

**EDIT**

I have found that if I capture a range, I can use it to deduce the sheet name I need:

```
Excel.Range result = _excel.InputBox(
                                     prompt,
                                     "Sheet Selection",
                                     Type.Missing,
                                     Type.Missing,
                                     Type.Missing,
                                     Type.Missing,
                                     Type.Missing,
                                     Type.Missing) as Excel.Range;

if (result == null)
   return null;
return result.Worksheet.Name;
```

Comment: please show all of the code where you are defining the COM Interop Excel Object..

Comment: Excel.Application _excel = this.Application; (where 'this' is an excel addin in C#)

Comment: paste all relevant code in the section where you posted your code..it's easier to read that way

Comment: I just did, in an edit, but here it is again, just for you, DJ KRAZE: (Excel.Application _excel = this.Application;) This declaration happens in 'ThisAddIn_Startup' method of my addin. Do you have some reason for wanting to know how the excel app is declared? Is it relevant in some way?